# Requested Resource not found when deleting a Twilio number

Tags: php, json, twilio

I am trying to remove a number from my Twilio account using the following code:

```
// remove the number from Twilio
$client = new Services_Twilio(TWILIO_SID, TWILIO_TOKEN);

try {

    // Remove the number
    $purchaseNumber = $client->account->incoming_phone_numbers->delete(array(
        "PhoneNumber" => "+447903000000"
    ));


} catch (Exception $e) {

    echo 'Error = '.$e->getMessage();

}
```

Which throws the following exception:

```
Error = The requested resource /2010-04-01/Accounts/jhsdkfjhdsjhf32370685sjhgfjhdsjfgsdjh/IncomingPhoneNumbers/Array.json was not found
```

I assume that the format of the request to delete the number is wrong but there doesn't seem to be any examples in the documentation on how to do it - can anyone shed any light on where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

So it seems that you cannot delete a number using the number - you have to use the SID which is returned when you purchase the number. Details here:

http://web.onassar.com/blog/2012/06/16/twilio-incoming-phone-numbers-releasing-deletion/